# selecting k items from X+Y items such that count of X is odd.

Tags: combinatorics

Given x and y denoting count of two different items, also given a value K.
We need to select a total of K items from those X+Y items such that the count of chosen X items is odd.
For example, X=4,Y=3,K=3.
then number of ways= (4C1)*(3C2)+(4C3)*(3C0)
here nCr denotes n!/(r!*(n-r)!)
Is there any formula to calculate this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a little confusion over the '$!$' sign:

$${n \choose r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$

Where:
$$n! = n\times(n-1)\times\dotsb\times1$$
$$r! = r\times(r-1)\times\dotsb\times1$$
And:
$$(n-r)! = (n-r)\times((n-r)-1)\times\dotsb\times1$$

For more info, read up about the [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20factorial%20of,convention%20for%20an%20empty%20product.) and [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).